# StyledComponents not being recognised+trouble with local font implementation in vite

Tags: fonts, styled-components, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwa6.png)
i have been using GlobalStyles to import some of the local fonts as well as apply some styles using the css root element and i am stuck due to a few issues:

1. I believe that the Styles are not being recognised i followed the recommended pattern and have imported GlobalStyles at the top of the linkTree and called it inside the App function.

frontPage which is the file where i am trying to use these styles is no recognising these styles
2.  I believe that react is not able to recognise any of my local fonts because the way i am trying to import them is not okay.

What i tried
2)For fonts:
I have searched the web extensively and even tried to create the vite.config.jsx file and do all that but on `npm run dev` it crashes. Would you please let me know how to implement it if i have my fonts under `src/assets/fonts`.I am using Vite and cant understand how to use unplug fonts in @font-face.